# Where to get SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server

Can some one please tell me if the edition even exists?
I am unable to find any downloads at MS not any specific information regarding the edition...

Anyway, in case it is not available to DL, can some one please tell me what version should I download that has all the tools included? - I need it for testing purposes (trial).

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this ( or something similar) is available in the technet subscription.

Check here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx

Comment: I found that also, but I am having problems locating the actual download page...

Comment: You need a technet subscription to be able to download them.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft website contains both a list of the available editions, as well as the trial downloads.  If you just search for your question almost verbatim in google, the top two links answer your question.

Here are the editions available for 2012:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions.aspx
```

Here is the trial download page:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/get-sql-server/try-it.aspx
```

Comment: Im sorry dude, but belive me I did check. MS states that Developer edition is not part of main editions (your page).In the pages you provided there is no information where can i download the developer edition...